# Check if user is granted permission explicit or through AD-group

Tags: 2010, permissions

I am trying to write custom code that will show extra content on a page for specific `users`. The users that should see the extra content should be those that are not given permission through a AD-group.

Is there a way to check if a user is granted `permission` to a `site` through a `AD-group`?

Comment: The only thing I have come up with so far is to. Get all AD-groups that has permissions on the site. Check these AD-groups if user is a member. IF not? Show content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have come up with a solution to check permission groups on a site to see if a user has been granted permissions through an AD-group or through a SharePoint permission group.

I will call this method when iterating all permission groups on a site. If the method answer comes back as true once, I will not show the extra content.

using System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement;

```
    public bool IsUserInSharePointGroup(string webUrl, string groupName, string username)
    {
        bool userIsInADGroup = false;

        SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate
        {
            try
            {
                SPWeb web = SPContext.Current.Web;

                // Find the group
                SPGroup group = web.SiteGroups[groupName];
                string upperCaseUserName = username.ToUpper();

                foreach (SPUser user in group.Users)
                {
                    // Check if this is an AD Group
                    if (!user.IsDomainGroup)
                    {
                        // Verify if the user name matches the user name in group
                        if (user.LoginName.ToUpper().Equals(upperCaseUserName))
                        {
                            userIsInADGroup= false;
                            continue;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // this is an AD group
                        var pc = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);
                        var myuser = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(pc, IdentityType.SamAccountName, username);
                        var mygroup = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(pc, user.LoginName);
                        if (myuser.IsMemberOf(mygroup))
                        {
                            userIsInADGroup = true;
                            return userIsInADGroup;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //Trace error
            }
        });
        return userIsInADGroup;
    }
```

The code has been stolen and edited from this location. http://www.bigscholar.com/2012/01/06/check-if-user-is-in-a-sharepoint-or-ad-group/

Answer (score 2):

Via PowerShell you can always check using this script

```
$urlWeb = "http://myweb"
Get-SPUser -Web $urlWeb | select UserLogin, @{name=”Exlicit given roles”;expression={$_.Roles}}, @{name=”Roles given via groups”;expression={$_.Groups | %{$_.Roles}}},Groups | format-Table -auto
```

And If you're using claims, please note that some users may be displayed both with and without a claims hash

```
UserLogin            Exlicit given roles Roles given via groups Groups           
---------            ------------------- ---------------------- ------           
i:0#.w|AD\admin      Full Control        Full Control           {Owner of Portal}
AD\admin                                                        {}               
c:0(.s|true                                                     {}               
AD\SP_Farm                                                      {}               
i:0#.w|AD\SP_Farm                                               {}               
i:0#.w|AD\SP_Install                     Full Control           {Owner of Portal}
i:0#.w|AD\User                                                  {}               
SHAREPOINT\system                                               {}
```

Comment: Sorry, my question was unclear and I have rewritten it. I want to check if users are granted permissions through an AD-group or not.

Comment: @Skaft Hmm. that's a little tougher to answer. I'll get back to you if I remember how to get AD-group permissions.

Answer (score 1):

Not done this before myself but it seems the `SPUser` class has a `Groups` property that:

> Gets the collection of groups of which the user is a member.

You could use this property to check if the user is a member of any groups in your code behind, and if not, show the extra content on the page.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spuser.groups.aspx

Comment: Sorry, but that was not what I was looking for. My question was unclear and I have rewritten it.